# ionic toggle-items in a list display bugs on android

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello in my angularjs/ionic application I have a list of toggle-items.

Well somehow if I switch some of the toggle-items I get display bugs like in the picture below. This behavior happens only with Android not iOS.

[image: toggle-bug-android]

Well this only happens when the white entries was former a activated toggle item. It also seems to be random wich of the active toggle items get white.

My code for this toggle-item list looks like here:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>

    <ion-list>
      <div>
        <ion-item class="item-stable">
          <i class="icon ion-chevron-up"></i>
          &nbsp;
          Test
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-accordion item-toggle">

          <i class="icon ion-clock"></i>

          blabla

          <label class="toggle toggle-calm">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <div class="track">
              <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
          </label>

        </ion-item>

        <label >test</label>

        <ion-item class="item-accordion item-toggle">

          <i class="icon ion-clock"></i>

          blabla

          <label class="toggle toggle-calm">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <div class="track">
              <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
          </label>

        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="item-accordion item-toggle">

          <i class="icon ion-clock"></i>

          blabla

          <label class="toggle toggle-calm">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <div class="track">
              <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
          </label>

        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="item-accordion item-toggle">

          <i class="icon ion-clock"></i>

          blabla

          <label class="toggle toggle-calm">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <div class="track">
              <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
          </label>

        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="item-accordion item-toggle">

          <i class="icon ion-clock"></i>

          blabla

          <label class="toggle toggle-calm">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <div class="track">
              <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
          </label>

        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="item-accordion item-toggle">

          <i class="icon ion-clock"></i>

          blabla

          <label class="toggle toggle-calm">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <div class="track">
              <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
          </label>

        </ion-item>
      </div>
    </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: is the question not clear enough ?